# Commerce 3 Subscription form

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to make a 2-step subscription process. Where someone clicks 'subscribe' and it takes them to a new page.

Free trial button goes to `url('subscribe?plan=' ~ plan.uid)`

I then retrieve that on the subscribe page with `{% set plan = craft.app.request.getParam('plan') %}`

How can I pass that UID into the gateway form? I use `{{ plan.gateway.getPaymentFormHtml({})|raw }}` but get `Impossible to access an attribute ("gateway") on a string variable ("2c98700c-0839232").`

Makes sense but I'm looking for a way to get the plan via the planUid. This is where my head goes, but I know it's not correct:

```
{% set chosenPlan = craft.app.request.getParam('plan') %}
{% set plan = craft.commerce.getPlans().getAllPlans().uid(chosenPlan) %}
{{ plan.gateway.getPaymentFormHtml({})|raw }}
```

Does anyone know how I could get this (or something like it) to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
{% set chosenPlan = craft.app.request.getParam('plan') %}
{% set plan = craft.commerce.getPlans().getPlanByUid(chosenPlan) %}
{{ plan.gateway.getPaymentFormHtml({})|raw }}
```